# Does this congruence equation system have no solutions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
9x \equiv 5 \pmod{10} \\ 
14x \equiv 8 \pmod{18} \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$m.c.m.(10,18)=2$

$2 \nmid (5+8)$

There are no integer solutions for this system?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) there are integer solutions for this system, indeed

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
9x ≡ 5 \pmod {10} \\ 
14x ≡ 8 \pmod {18} \\ 
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
9x ≡ 5 \pmod {2} \\ 
9x ≡ 5 \pmod {5} \\ 
14x ≡ 8 \pmod {9} \\ 
14x ≡ 8 \pmod {2} \\ 
\end{array}
\right.\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x ≡ 1 \pmod {2} \\ 
4x ≡ 0 \pmod {5} \\ 
5x ≡ -1 \pmod {9} \\ 
0 ≡ 0 \pmod {2} \\ 
\end{array}
\right.\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x ≡ 1 \pmod {2} \\ 
x ≡ 0 \pmod {5} \\ 
7\cdot 5x ≡ -7 \pmod {9} \\ 
\end{array}
\right.\iff\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x ≡ 1 \pmod {2} \\ 
x ≡ 0 \pmod {5} \\ 
x ≡ 7\pmod {9} \\ 
\end{array}
\right.$$

which solutions are $$x\equiv 25 \pmod {90} \iff x=25+90k$$

Comment: You can't apply the CRT where there are just 2 equations!

Comment: Why not? Note that CRT guarantees that the final system has solution.

Comment: I can't understand why.

Comment: @Jonsa From the original system you need to decompose the equations in prime factors. EG: $9x\equiv 5 \pmod{10}\iff 9x=5+10k \iff  4x\equiv 0 \pmod{5} \land x\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ and so on. If the equations of the final system are compatible then by CRT we know that the solution exists.